# tinymce GET http://fast.fonts error in console

Tags: tinymce

This code is inside `head` tag:

```
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
    selector: '#editor',
    theme: 'modern',
    plugins: ['autoresize advlist autolink lists link image charmap hr anchor pagebreak',
    'searchreplace visualblocks visualchars code',
    'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
    'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools'
    ],
   toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons',
   image_advtab: true,
   templates: [
   { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
   { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
   ],
   content_css: ['//fast.fonts.net/cssapi/e6dc9b99-64fe-4292-ad98-6974f93cd2a2.css',
    '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
   ]
   });
</script>
```

Console:

```
GET http://fast.fonts.net/cssapi/e6dc9b99-64fe-4292-ad98-6974f93cd2a2.css
```

Any help?

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, justo eripuit eos eu. Ex quo viris facilis imperdiet, quidam pertinacia philosophia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you copied the code from one of the TinyMCE demos on their web site... if you don't have an account with Fonts.com then referencing those fonts in your application will lead to an error.

You can learn more about what the `content_css` configuration option does here:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css